# How to ensure Thread.Sleep() is Synchronous?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've written a process in C# that depends on one process to run for x seconds, that process to complete, and then run another process for y seconds. To facilitate this, I'm using `Thread.Sleep()`. However, what happens in reality is that the first process begins, the second process begins, and both processes complete after x and y seconds, respectively. Here is a snippet of code:

```
core.ProcessOne(DurationX);
core.ProcessTwo(DurationY);
.
.
.
public void ProcessOne(double Time)
{
// Start Process
Thread.Sleep((Int32)(Time * 1000))
// End Process
}
public void ProcessTwo(double Time)
{
Thread.Sleep((Int32) MixingTime * 1000); // It's just a constant amount of time to wait
// Start Process
Thread.Sleep((Int32)(Time * 1000))
// End Process
}
```

How do I fix this so that Process 1 must complete for Process 2 to begin? In other words, I need this program to be synchronous.

I don't intend on using multithreading, or synchronous processes for that matter. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: None of the code you've posted is asynchronous, so what exactly are you asking?

Comment: It's not clear what you are willing to achieve. If you just want to start process 2 after end of process 1 - you don't need anything, just write these processes one by one. If you want them to run in parallel - you have to use multi threading.

Comment: Are you using `Process.Start` to start these "processes"? How are you ending them?

Comment: @Flydog57 Sorry, I'm not actually using `Process`. It's literally just some computation.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I want a Thread to finish sleeping before the other threads proceed. How can I achieve this?

Comment: There's nothing that can be answered here. We don't know what you are trying to do. If your start and end process notes are simple method calls and do no multi threading (or multi processing) then you simply have a poorly coded synchronous processing flow. Otherwise, there's not much that can be said

Comment: If you could explain what you are trying to do, and the environment you are working in (a console app, a service, a UI app, a web app.. , then we might be able to suggest a solution. Consider reading up on async and await

Comment: By the way, starting things is easy. Ending them is hard. In the general case, "killing" a process or a thread (or worse, "just some computation") will often result in *bad things happening*

Comment: Code  shown in the question behaves exactly as asked in the question. There is absolutely no way for `core.ProcessTwo(DurationY);` to start before previous line is complete (in code as shown, if that is not [MCVE] please [edit] the post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your ProcessOne runs asynchronous.
Then you can use a ManualResetEventSlim

```
var re = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);

ProcessOne() {

    // Do lots of work

    // at the end of ProcessOne:
    re.Set();
}

re.Wait(); // wait for re.Set();

// start your second load of work
ProcessTwo() {

}
```

Comment: This answer will do. Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this?

Comment: @FurkanToprak depending on the context this might be the elegant version, because you don't need to create a new task and the overhead of that. You can wrap this function so you no longer see the ManualResetEventSlim. Also you would want to do this inside a try, finally { re.set() } block, so `re.Set()` will always be called even if your function throws an error.

Comment: If there is no asynchronous code and not process/thread creation as OP claims there is absolutely no reason to use that type of synchronization. @Charles please [edit] your answer to clarify what question it answers.

Answer (score 0):

Thread.Sleep() runs on whichever thread calls it. You are either calling those methods from different threads or starting a new process or thread in one or both of those methods.

Im guessing you actually start a new process in there and expect it to finish before your code continues on. You have to explicitly wait for the process to exit if that's the case.

Edit: Call WaitForExit() on a Process reference to wait for it to finish. Call Join() on a thread to wait for it to finish. Though there's no point in starting a new thread if that's all your doing. It seems more likely there's more to the problem and you need to use more sophisticated synchronization like locks or semaphore's.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: You save a reference to the Process and call WaitForExit on it

Comment: TS doesn't want separate OS processes, it's just "computation processes"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the solution is something like this.

```
var task1 = core.ProcessOne(DurationX);
var task2 = core.ProcessTwo(DurationY);

await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
.
.
.
public async Task ProcessOne(double Time) // I assume Time is in seconds
{
// Start Process
await Task.Delay(Time * 1000);
// End Process
}
public async Task ProcessTwo(double Time)
{
await Task.Delay(MixingTime * 1000);
// Start Process
await Task.Delay(Time * 1000);
// End Process
}
```

Also if you have some event in second process after which you want to start first one it is better to use `ManualResetEvent` as @Charles suggested in his answer.

Comment: What is the purpose of Task.WhenAll()? Does that ensure that the two Tasks complete one after the other? I can't find many details in the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Task.WhenAll() waits for both task to complete. The order is not its concern.

Comment: It is a concern for me. Does your suggestion ensure that ProcessOne() runs first, completes, and then ProcessTwo() runs and completes second?

Comment: No, it is for opposite. If you need to run second process only after completion of first processing, you don't need to use any synchronization - it will be synchronous by default. Just call this methods one after another. If they have asynchronous nature - it is possible to just wait for the first to complete using `await` or something else. Pls add more details to your question.

Comment: My actual code has no synchronous nature. However, my issue is that my previous code allowed for ProcessTwo() to start before ProcessOne() had finished. How can I fix this?

Comment: You have to lock Process2 execution. @Charles solution will do the trick. Speaking shortly: create ManualResetEvent in false state, pass it to both processes, in the end of process1 call `set` and in the begining of process2 call `wait`. The second process will block current thread and wait while this event is not set.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive help. I'd like to accept your answer, but @Charles was the first to answer and ended giving me the tools I needed.